# protobuff-net save / load static fields

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Is there anyway to save static fields or optimally a full static class in ProtoBuffNet.  The person.bin size is 0 after saving, so I believe the issue is that it is not saving any static fields.

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProtoBuffNet
{
    [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
    public class Person
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public static int Id = -1;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public static string Name = "";
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Person person = new Person();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void setPerson()
        {
            Person.Id = 12345;
            Person.Name = "Fred";
        }

        public static void resetPerson()
        {
            Person.Id = -1;
            Person.Name = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setPerson();
            using (var file = File.Create("person.bin"))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(file, person);
            }
            // person Here:
            //  person.Id = 12345
            //  person.Name = "Fred"
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetPerson();
            Person newPerson;
            using (var file = File.OpenRead("person.bin"))
            {
                newPerson = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
            }
            // What happens:
            //  newPerson.Id = -1
            //  newPerson.Name = ""

            // What I want:
            //  newPerson.Id = 12345
            //  newPerson.Name = "Fred"
        }
    }
}
```

The above code runs, but appears not to be saving the static fields.  It would be optimal if Person class could be static as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the library  is oriented around instances - usually objects. Frankly, most serialization tools are.  You could fake it with a shim object that just proxies instance values to the static members, but...  it isn't specifically a targeted scenario.